# How to turn off Django's i18n formatting for numbers, for just one number in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a template, where *nearly* all of the numbers need to be i18n'd.  i.e. commas instead of decimal points for Europe.

One number needs to be displayed with a decimal point at all times.

How can I achieve this?

I've already tried using a template filter (below), but the comma remained.

filter:

```
@register.filter
def raw_float(value):
    return "" + str(value)
```

template:

```
{{ event.lat|raw_float }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attempted code works perfectly.  I just made a typo elsewhere which confused me.